# Do intelligent people tend to stay up later?

Tags: sleep, intelligence

I heard that people with high IQs stay up late. I found [this article](http://www.esquire.com/blogs/news/smart-means-sex-and-drugs-and-staying-up) which in turn refers to this study:

- S. Kanazawa, K. Perina, [Why night owls are more intelligent](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/KANAZAWA/pdfs/PAID2009.pdf), Personality and Individual Differences 47 (2009) 685–690

> More
>   intelligent children are more likely to grow up to be nocturnal
>   adults who go to bed late and wake up late on both weekdays
>   and weekends

Is the science sound? I find this strange because there is the claim that successful people get up early.

Comment: I'm quite sure that we already had a very similar question, but I can't find it.

Comment: There is a very similar question here, but it has not been answered. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15200/are-intelligent-people-more-nocturnal-than-people-not-considered-intelligent

Comment: @Jeroen I'd say it's a duplicate, but apparently you can't vote to close as a duplicate if there other one doesn't have answers.

Comment: @rob unless you are a mod ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz, now you are just showing off.